# How to query on a specific Elasticsearch type and fetch records matching a keyword?

Tags: elasticsearch, querydsl

I have built the following ElasticSearch (POST) query in order to fetch records matching will following criterias :
-select type : "server"
-select fields : "servername", "silo", "packages.displayname", "packages.displayversion","environment"

```
{
    "size": 10,
    "_source" : ["servername", "silo", "packages.displayname", "packages.displayversion","environment"],
    "query": {
          "type" : {
            "value" : "server"
        }
    }
}
```

It works !

The problem is when I want to add the following condition :
-"packages.displayname" = "Google Chrome"

```
{
    "size": 10,
    "_source" : ["servername", "silo", "packages.displayname", "packages.displayversion","environment"],
    "query": {
          "type" : {
            "value" : "server"
        },
        "match" : {"packages.displayname" : "Google Chrome"}
    }
}
```

It doesn't work ! the following error is raised :

```
"type": "parsing_exception",
                "reason": "[type] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]",
                "line": 8,
                "col": 9
```

I'm totally noob in ElasticSearch..can somebody help me to figure out how I should write the Query please ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to build a bool query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match": {
          "packages.displayname": "Google Chrome"
        }
      },
       "must": {
        "type": {
          "value": "server"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```